# best way to pass GUI references to other classes that edit them

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have a client/server MMORPG I am working on and I want to do things correctly(as impossible as it is).  My questions is: What is the best way to pass references to my GUI items(JInternalFrame, JPanels, etc.) to my class that listens to commands/replies from the server.  Right now this is what I have going on, which will soon grow quite large.

```
MyCommandReciever(DataInputStream commandIn, DefaultListModel modelUserList, JInternalFrame skillsFrame, Container skillsPanelHeader, Container skillsPanelContent, JInternalFrame characterFrame){
    this.commandIn = commandIn;
    this.modelUserList = modelUserList;
    this.skillsFrame = skillsFrame;
    this.skillsPanelHeader = skillsPanelHeader;
    this.skillsPanelContent = skillsPanelContent;
    this.characterFrame = characterFrame;
}
```

I don't want to keep passing more and more JInternalFrames to MyCommandReciever.

Does it make sense to do something like this??

```
Component[] c = panel.getComponents();
for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(c[i].getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Or is there a way that I can create an instance of my Main class(which includes my GUI), from within my main class, and pass that to MyCommandReciever so it has access to everything(maybe like this):

```
MyCommandReciever(DataInputStream commandIn, DefaultListModel modelUserList, MyClient m){
```

If this last approach is the way to go(which I'm hoping it isn't, do I need to pass it from the class that creates an instance of it(Character.java creates instance of MyClient.java), to itself(MyClient.java), and then pass it from MyClient.java to MyCommandReciever.java?

Sorry if that last question was too confusing... let me break it down:

Inside Character.java:

```
if (playSuccess.contains("true")){
    z++; //to turn off the commandIn functionality in Character screen when MyClient is running
    frame.dispose();
    new MyClient(accountName, playWho, commandIn, messageIn, commandOut, messageOut, sM, sC);
```

Inside MyClient.java:

```
commandReciever = new MyCommandReciever(commandIn, modelUserList, skillsFrame, skillsPanelHeader, skillsPanelContent, characterFrame);
```

so in the character.java I would have to create instance of MyClient(and assign to variable) but at the same time pass that assigned variable to MyClient. (now that I'm typing this it doesn't even seem possible).

Please guide me :D  Clearly I wrapped my brain on this last idea.

Comment: Just to clarify: Every Object in Java is passed by reference.

Comment: So MyCommandReceiver should get information from the server and update your GUI elements? I would rephrase your title and retag. Because this is about GUI design.

Comment: You should not pass references of UI elements to other classes. The UI elements should only be changed by the UI classes. See [MVC-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: @hellectronic *Ahem* http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach that I decided to go with.  Thanks for the other advice however it seemed a bit complex for my needs:

In my main gui class:

```
commandReciever = new MyCommandReciever(commandIn, this); //passing in instance of my main gui class
```

In my command receiever class(class that talks to server):

```
MyClient m; //for access to the GUI pieces

MyCommandReciever(DataInputStream commandIn, MyClient m){
    this.commandIn = commandIn;
    this.m = m;
}
```

Example of how I edit my main gui class's components from my command receiver class:

```
m.modelUserList.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < CharactersList.length; i++){
    m.modelUserList.addElement(CharactersList[i]);
}
```

Comment: This solution is what I suggested, except that you aren't hiding the necessary messiness of the "main class" behind a clean interface. If your project is small it's unlikely that you'll run into trouble, but in a larger project having unrestricted access between two modules (like here the gui and the command receiver) can become a problem. E.g. imagine there are parts of the GUI that the command receiver will not/should not be use, but now you have no way of knowing if you it does.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is use the pattern called  "observer" or "event source":

1. Define an interface between the command receiver and the main class, with methods that the command receiver should call when something interesting happens.
2. (Obviously the command receiver should hold a refence to an object that implements this interface to be able to send events.)
3. Implement the interface in the main class--either by the main class itself or by a nested class--and respond to events from the command receiver by updating the interface. Pass the implementation to the command receiver.

This way the command receiver and user interface are completely decoupled, and if at some point you decide to use something other than `JInternalFrame` for data display you don't have to change code in hundreds of places.

You could also consider using MVC or one of its many siblings..

Comment: I appreciate the help and I did most of the reading that you suggested, but it seemed overly complex for a one man team, working on a game that wont be re-purposed.  I sincerely do appreciate the help because just typing my question helped me come up with my solution, which I will add here to help any others in my same boat.